# PEAP MS-CHAPv2 brute force attack

Tags: brute-force, sniffing, 802.1x

I have a 802.1x switch and a client authenticated using PEAP-MS-CHAPv2.
I sniffed the traffic using a HUB between the client and the switch.
How can I use the captured informations to perform a brute-force attack?